# How to get fetchall to only get one input per row and to get multiple results

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and MySQL to retrieve  and to print the output from the mysql database; however, when I run through the following code I get two results from the echo instead of one:

```
<?php require('includes/config.php');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select username From members where resetToken like 'yes';");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($result[0] as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
?>
```

Also when I run the sql through phpmyadmin it returns multiple users but when I run it through the php page it only returns one. Also the config.php contains all of the database info so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one result because you're only checking the very first result (at index 0). Iterate first over the results, then over their values:

```
<?php
require('includes/config.php');

$stmt = $db->prepare("select username From members where resetToken like 'yes';");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $values)
    foreach($values as $value) {
        echo "$value <br>";
    }
}
?>
```